# Id like to search cloudant by words and a range of timestamped dates via node-red

Tags: search, node-red, cloudant

My cloudant database was created with the following: msg.payload via tweetnode to cloudant

```
{ 
   "timestamp" : msg.tweet.timestamp_ms, 
   "tweet" : msg.tweet.text, 
   "sentiment" : msg.sentiment.score
}
```

I would like to search the tweets by word and a range of dates. Then save the results by tagging the tweets found back to cloudant via node-red.

This seems like a routine thing people do. I have not found any flows that do this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Here's an index Ive created and a query but no joy    function(doc) {
  index("default", doc._id);
 if (doc.timestamp) {
 index("timestamp", doc.timestamp, {"store": true});
 }
 if (doc.tweet) {
index("tweet", doc.tweet, {"store": true});
}
if (doc.sentiment) {
index("sentiment", doc.sentiment, {"store": true});
}
}

query: "tweet : esports<string>", This gives me 404 errors

Comment: I also created this view function (doc) {
if (typeof(doc.tweet)=="string") {
index("tweet", doc.tweet);
}
} and then entered this search via injection node and function node  msg.payload = {
     "q":"tweet:keyword",
     "include_docs": true,
     "limit": 10
}
    
return msg; also 404 error

Comment: these are just two attempts after 20 or so I came here

Answer (score 0):

Your index look right. Maybe the 404 was caused by the white spaces you have around the colon. Here a quick example: https://gist.github.com/lgfa29/d965e66bf1ffa0fff7ab26f314ea98de

You can copy this JSON document, click on the three dashes in the top right of the Node-RED editor and select Import > Clipboard. Then just paste the JSON content there and drop the nodes somewhere. You will also need to update the Cloudant node to point to your database and search index.

To query using search indexes you can use the [Lucene query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lucene-query.html), so to search for a range you would do something like `timestamp:[1551464030329 TO 1551465568517]`

Here is a sample I deployed: https://node-red-pet-dev.mybluemix.net/search?from=0&to=1651464030328&tweet=zebra* (sorry, my tweets are not very imaginative)